# Powershell: Adding element to hashtable failed

Tags: powershell, hashtable, element

```
PS C:\Users\Hind> $b=@{}
PS C:\Users\Hind> $b+={k="a";v="b"}
A hash table can only be added to another hash table.
At line:1 char:1
+ $b+={k="a";v="b"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddHashTableToNonHashTable
```

Why did it fail? How can I add one element to a hashtable successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correction, this fails because you are missing the `@` character in front of `@{k="a";b="b"}`

```
PS C:\Users\Hind> $b=@{}
PS C:\Users\Hind> $b+=@{k="a";v="b"}
```

`@{}` is declaring a new hash table. `{}` is a script block. They are not the same.

Comment: So, can I append one hashtable to another? Any syntax like this? I'm not sure if Powershell supports any kind of operator overloading?

Comment: {} is just a closure in PowerShell without @{} and so the operands are of different types if @ is omitted.

Comment: i tried : D:\> $myhash=@{k1="va1";k2="val2"} PS D:\> $myhash+={k3="val3"}
A hash table can only be added to another hash table. Still doesn't work?

Comment: $myhash+=@{k3="val3"}

Comment: @{} = declaring a new hash table.  {} is a script block. They aren't the same.

Answer (score 3):

Initialising the hashtable should be with round bracket instead of curly brackets

```
$b=@()
$b+=@{k="a";v="b"}
```